# JSON response from Jquery.ajax is rounding larger number so I can't get correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am performing an AJAX get request and this is the response I get in a program like Paw/Postman:

```
[
  {
    "registrantKey": 4131401026087862797,
  }
]
```

However when I do:

```
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $.each(data, function(index){
    console.log(data[index].registrantKey);
    });
})
```

it is treating this registrant key value as a large number and is rounding off the last numbers so the value being printed to the console is: 4131401026087863000. How do I get the original value as shown in Paw/Postman. I don't need to perform any math operations on it I just need the value. I tried experimenting with the toString() method but I couldn't get this to work. Your help would be much appreciated.

**update**
Unfortunately this just isn't possible in javascript. The only solution is to use another language or to try and get original developers to return value as a string. Thanks Rory and Madalin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access to your json as string and not as object (maybe in the jqXHR object), you can transform all numbers to string like this :

`jsonText = jsonText.replace(/([^\D]\d+[^\D])/g, "\"$1\"").replace(/""/g, "\"");`

(Be careful with my regex, i don't really sure if it works in any case)

And after load your jsonText as an object.

Comment: Thanks Fefux, in my particular case I could access the response text and get this value. I am new to Javascript so didn't really know this was possible but it worked a treat! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to the precision of JS and has nothing to do with jQuery or AJAX. In JS a number can only contain a maximum of 16 integers, up to a maximum of `9,007,199,254,740,991` (aka [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER))

If you need to display a larger number then you would have to work with it as a string, but be aware that it will be rounded down to the max precision JS can use if you attempt to convert it to a Number type.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I get what you're saying but how do I actually get it into a string? The call is being made to a Citrix API so I have no control over the length of the value being returned. As I said I tried toString method but this didn't seem to work..maybe it was how I used it I am not sure.

Comment: You can't do it from JS I'm afraid as it's too late at that stage. It needs to be a string when it's provided to JS from your server

Comment: Thanks Rory, that is really annoying though. Like I get why there's a limit to the length of numbers in javascript but there should be a way to just render the whole response a string and pull this apart, because as I said I don't need it to be an integer anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My first solution was:
Send json string as text/plain from backend;
With horroble regex replace numbers with strings then parse to object.

Then after some bugs we modified json serializer(jackson lib) to write as string if value is instance of Number;
Send string as application/json from backend;
Removed frontend code since jquery does parsing if content type is json;

Operating with big numbers is done by BigNumber JQ plugin